# Reorganize Data in Google Drive Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have data that looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| Date | Name | Cost |
+------+------+------+
| 1/16 | A    |   30 |
| 2/16 | B    |   20 |
| 2/16 | A    |   10 |
| 4/16 | C    |   11 |
| 4/16 | C    |   15 |
| 5/16 | B    |    6 |
+------+------+------+
```

And I would like to reformat it like this:

```
+------+----+----+----+
| Date | A  | B  | C  |
+------+----+----+----+
| 1/16 | 30 |    |    |
| 2/16 |    | 20 |    |
| 2/16 | 10 |    |    |
| 4/16 |    |    | 11 |
| 4/16 |    |    | 15 |
| 5/16 |    |  6 |    |
+------+----+----+----+
```

I was able to get the vertical date column copied/duplicated with something like this: `=ArrayFormula(Worksheet!A2:A7)`

And I've been fiddling around with getting the Names across the top with this: `=TRANSPOSE(Worksheet!C2:C7)`, but that won't work because it duplicates the Names.

Furthermore, I have no idea how to get the cost to display where the date and name intersect.

Is this possible/sane to accomplish this in Google Drive spreadsheets?

If Google Sheets/Spreadsheets are not the right tool for the job, what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the PivotTable Report:

[image]

And the use the following as fields:

[image]

Of course, you can now copy the parts to need (thus ignoring the totals) and paste in another sheet or something or alter the settings to remove the totals.

[Link to the above workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dFQxVDU2bV9JUXRFNWx4dXBZcHZDbmc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh oops, I just noticed that this is not exactly what you might be looking for since the dates are being grouped... But if that's fine, then I'm glad.

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce the table with the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343?hl=en) function, but the data has to be manipulated a bit first:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF({1,0,0},A2:A+ROW(A2:A)/10000000000,A2:C),"select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col2 != '' group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Date'",0))`

You will also need to apply a date format to the first column in the output.